# JavaScript: declare all members in constructor for documentary purposes?

Tags: javascript, coding-style

Should one declare and initialize all members of a class already in the constructor's function even if set to a meaningful value at a later point? And would you prefer `null` or `undefined`?

```
function MyClass() {
  /** @type {Number} [describtion] */  // first approach
  this._member1 = null;

  /** @type {Object} [describtion] */  // second approach
  this._member2 = undefined;
}

MyClass.prototype.work = function() {  // called later
  this._member1 = 42;
  this._member2 = { 'foo': 13 };

  /** @type {String} [describtion] */  // third approach
  this._member3 = "bar";
};
```

Comment: It all depends on your needs.
if you don't set a value to variable, it is by default considered undefined. "null" has its own uses, for example when I import API data some properties of my objects have a "null" value, to indicate that nothing has been set. While an undefined property means that it doesnt exist in the object. (but this is from an API data standpoint).
IMO, you should declare all REQUIRED properties in your class function, and append other properties on a per-need basis. (i.e. if function work() is never called on your object, it will never need _member3...

Comment: Thanks, never-called functions is a good point.

Comment: also keep in mind that JS is a dynamic language, objects are transformable even after being generated from a constructor function. Don't limit the expressiveness of the language by trying to imitate static language habits.

Comment: added as answer, so you can mark this question solved. Was there anything else you needed to inquire about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on your needs.

If you don't set a value to variable, it is by default considered undefined.

"null" has its own uses, for example when I import API data some properties of my objects have a "null" value, to indicate that nothing has been set. While an undefined property means that it doesn't exist in the object. (but this is from an API data standpoint).

IMO, you should declare all REQUIRED properties in your class function, and append other properties on a per-need basis. (i.e. if `function work()` is never called on your object, it will never need `_member3`

Also, keep in mind that JS is a dynamic language, objects are transformable even after being generated from a constructor function. Don't limit the expressiveness of the language by trying to imitate static language habits.